# Unable to build QEMU 2.12 with WHPX (Windows Hypervisor Platform) enabled

Tags: windows, virtualization, hyper-v, qemu

[If this is in the wrong StackExchange feel free to redirect me.]

I've been interested in using QEMU for a while but also wish to use Hyper-V for Docker on Windows. I discovered that the new WHPX accelerator is available in QEMU 2.12 experimentally.

However, I have not found instructions on how to build with --enable-whpx configured. I copied the WinHvEmulation, WinHvPlatform, and WinHvPlatformDefs header files from the v1803 Windows SDK include headers to my MinGW64 include file, which is necessary for configure to "work." After configuring successfully, during the make step, I get the error:

```
C:/Users/lmcdougald/qemu_build/qemu/target/i386/whpx-all.c:27:10: fatal error: whp-dispatch.h: No such file or directory
#include "whp-dispatch.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I haven't found any resources to resolve this issue, including my best attempt at reading QEMU mailing lists.

Note: I lack the reputation to create a "whpx" tag, if necessary please assist with that as well.

Comment: Based on the error, you are missing, one of the required header files needed to build the project.

Comment: [This is a known problem](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/qemu-devel/2018-06/msg01203.html).  [I was unable to confirm if the `Paolo Bonzini` ever added it to the make/configure file.](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/qemu-devel/2018-06/msg00764.html)

Comment: Feel free to post that as an answer since I specified 2.12 in the question explicitly, and the file is clearly not present nor generated from the tagged 2.12 qemu repository.

Thank you for finding that correspondence, surprised that didn't turn up in my searches.

Comment: I don't feel submitting an answer that only indicates that the make/configure file isn't correct, should be considered an answer to this question unless I am willing to determine the problem then provide a fix.  Since I cannot make heads or tails of the repository since 2.11.2 and 2.12.0 configuration file appears to be identical.  I am left scratching my head.

Comment: Make/configure files are correct in the master branch. There isn't a release with the file yet and the file was only finally committed less than a week ago (which explains why I didn't find it, it wasn't there when I was looking).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Courtesy [a link](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/qemu-devel/2018-06/msg01203.html) from [Ramhound](https://superuser.com/users/83283/ramhound), it turns out this file was mistakenly not included in time for the 2.12 release. This file is included as of a June 28 commit ([github](https://github.com/qemu/qemu/commit/93d1499c8119989e3eb9a6936c5a18aaaaca6330) / [git.qemu.org](https://git.qemu.org/?p=qemu.git;a=commit;h=93d1499c8119989e3eb9a6936c5a18aaaaca6330)). Building with --enable-whpx configured works as long as WinHvEmulation, WinHvPlatform, and WinHvPlatformDefs are included.